# Extract Partition and remove Partition-Table

Tags: linux, partitioning

Hy,
Situation under Debian Linux, Kernel 2.6.26-2:
On a Block-Device (/dev/vdb) is a partition-table specifying one partition (/dev/vdb1) which contains a ext3-filesystem.
I want to remove the partition-table and make the partition-data directly available under (/dev/vdb).

The only possibility which came to my mind was to copy the data from the partition to another device, remove the partition-table and directly create the filesystem on /dev/vdb, mount it and copy the data back.

Is there a faster solution which doesnt involve such a long downtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can backup data directly copying blocks (`dd if=/dev/vdb1 of=.../backup`), then copy it back overwriting everything (`dd if=.../backup of=/dev/vdb`) and then resize filesystem to match device size directly with `resize2fs` or with a tool like `parted` or `gparted`.

Comment: Is it really possible to _directly_ save data on a block device, without using a partition? This would be completely new to me. I mean, with the ability to use it like any other device with partitions.

Comment: There is **no difference** between a whole block device and partition when it comes to reading or writing. Really. Everything you can do with a partition you can do with a block device too: creating filesystem, mounting, etc...

Comment: Well, didn't know that, thanks for the enlightenment! :)